# ValueError: "Empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words"

Tags: python

```
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word')
for each in (train_incidents_word_issue["Summary"].index):
    text_issue_list = [data_word_issue["Summary"][each]]
    sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(text_issue_list)
    frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
    bi_grams_issue_df = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])
    data_word_issue["data_issue_count"][each] = bi_grams_issue_df[bi_grams_issue_df.index.str.contains("^data issue$")]["frequency"].sum()
```

> I am getting the below error:

> ValueError
>  in 
> 5 for each in (train_incidents_word_issue["Summary"].index):
> 6    text_issue_list = [data_word_issue["Summary"][each]]
> ----> 7    sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(text_issue_list)
> 8    frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
> 9    bi_grams_issue_df = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), >columns=['frequency'])
>
> **ValueError:** Empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words>
>
> **Help me understand the error and recommended solution...i have just started with python**

Comment: Used the below code
word_vectorizer.fit_transform(text_issue_list.split('\n'))

Getting the below error
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for your vocabulary

```
word_vectorizer.fit_transform(text_issue_list.split('\n'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but getting the error now as

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You need to convert the list to string i guess